# How to rename a worksheet in several excel files, and modify the same cells in each worksheet using VB for each loop

Tags: excel, foreach, vbscript

I'm attempting to write a script that opens 5 different excel files, renames a worksheet in each file, and modifies the contents of several cells in each file, all in a "for each" loop. So far I can't even rename the worksheets...

I am working with the "for each" loop function, but can't quite figure out how to reference the Dim variable in the code

```
'launch Excel and open file
Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim names(i)
names(0)="VCS"
names(1)="VRS"
names(2)="VIN"
names(3)="VEU"
names(4)="VGT"
for i = 0 to 4
Set xlFile = xlObj.WorkBooks.Open("c:\warem32\EIA_Demand\NG_CONS_SUM_A_EPG0_" & names(i) & "_MMCF_M.xls")
'turn off screen alerts
xlObj.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'change sheet to desired worksheet name
Worksheets.Name("Data 1").Name = "Data1"
Next
xlFile.Close True
next
xlObj.Quit
```

Just for reference the name of the first referenced should be:
c:\warem32\EIA_Demand\NG_CONS_SUM_A_EPG0_VCS_MMCF_M.xls

IS it possible to reference the x value within the line of code that opens the excel file (specifically, where I have the characters ("x") in the code)?

If I can code this correctly, each iteration through the loop will alter the file name, and allow the script to select a different file, renaming the "data 1" tab to "Data1". The code currently does not work at all. I would like to also modify several cells in row 3 of the data1 worksheet using a nested loop, but figured I'd start with this first.
Thank you!

Comment: `"c:\warem32\EIA_Demand\NG_CONS_SUM_A_EPG0_(" & x & ")_MMCF_M.xls"` where `x` is a string (I assume `names(i)` would be the string in question? in which case put `"c:\warem32\EIA_Demand\NG_CONS_SUM_A_EPG0_(" & names(i) & ")_MMCF_M.xls"` in a loop (`for i = 0 to 4`)

Comment: Also: no need to loop through all worksheets, `Worksheets("Data 1").Name = "Data1"` should do what you want

Comment: Thank you for the help!
It seems like I'd have to reference the name of the dim (in this case, "names", in the for i = 0 to 4. Is that correct?
I have updated the code above to reflect the changes I've made for your reference. Can you let me know what I'm missing?
Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'launch Excel and open file
Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'turn off screen alerts
xlObj.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim MyNames As Variant
MyNames = Array("VCS", "VRS", "VIN", "VEU", "VGT")
for i = LBound(MyNames) To UBound(MyNames)
    Set xlFile = xlObj.WorkBooks.Open("c:\warem32\EIA_Demand\NG_CONS_SUM_A_EPG0_(" & MyNames(i) & ")_MMCF_M.xls")

    'change sheet to desired worksheet name
    Worksheets.Name("Data 1").Name = "Data1"

    xlFile.Close True

Next i
```

(FYI, this is untested, but, I believe, should work)

Comment: Thank you! I think maybe there is in issue with what the file name ends up being after referencing the loop variable, but I'm not sure.
It should end up being:
c:\warem32\EIA_Demand\NG_CONS_SUM_A_EPG0_VCS_MMCF_M.xls
How would we code the reference to the loop variable for that to be the file name/path?